# Anime that features an app that predicts how and when you die. The protagonist can summon a white lion on a phone application

Tags: story-identification, anime

Looking for the name of the anime that features an app that predicts how and when you die. The protagonist died in the train incident (not sure), and after waking up, he can summon a white lion on a phone application. I forgot the title and I remembered it airing on HERO TV.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [*Devil Survivor 2: The Animation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Survivor_2:_The_Animation) (2013)?

> One Sunday afternoon, Hibiki Kuze and Daichi Shijima receive **macabre videos from the Nicaea website which predict their deaths mere seconds before they are involved in a gruesome train accident.** They are spared however, when a Demon Summoning App installs itself on their phones and allows the duo and schoolmate Io Nitta to escape from carnivorous monsters feasting on the dead in the wrecked subway station. The trio are shocked to discover a massive catastrophe on the surface and take refuge in Roppongi with other panicked citizens. Suddenly, when a creature known as Dubhe (ドゥベ, Duube) appears and attacks the crowd, **Hibiki puts a stop to the carnage by summoning a demon from the app** and destroying the creature.

<sup>- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Survivor_2:_The_Animation (emphasis mine)</sup>

Wikipedia's [List of programs aired by Hero TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_aired_by_Hero) article states that this is one of the animes aired by Hero TV.

See this Youtube video of the first episode which features the Nicaea website/app and death prediction. (Relevant part starts at 05:32.)